# Calculate sides of square and skew needed to create a rhomboid with given diagonal lengths

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangle with sides A and B.

[image: Figure1]

I want to create 4 html elements with shape and size like the one marked in red here.

I think i can do this using `transform: skew()`. My problem is, given the rectangle with height A and width B, how to i create the figure in red? Its long diagonal needs to be equal to B and its short diagonal needs to be equal to A.

Sorry this might be more of a math question.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea easier than using skew. You can rely on multipe background in order to create the shape inside the given rectangle:

```css
.rect {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right, red 49.8%,transparent 50%) top right,
    linear-gradient(to top left, red 49.8%,transparent 50%) top left,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom right,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, red 49.8%,transparent 50%) bottom left;
  background-size:50% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```